# How to extract latitude and longitude from firebase whenever they get updated?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

How to extract latitude and longitude from firebase whenever they get updated? When i am trying to get it it returns Both the key-value pair, All i need is latest value.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Routes").child("route1").child("Location");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {[enter image description here][1]
            String lat = snapshot.child("Latitude").getValue().toString();
            Toast.makeText(ParentsMapActivity.this, lat.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Frank's solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `Latitude` and `Longitude` nodes don't contain numeric values, but instead contain a child nodes that contains that value. From the looks of it, the extra child nodes (starting with `-M`) were generated by calling `push()`. If you remove that extra `push()` call, your code can read the values from the resulting data.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, the latest database value from `firebase` must be obtained to plot on map .In mapsActivity, you can try the this.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    //get instance of firebase database
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    //look for name from reference
    database.child(getName!!).get().addOnSuccessListener {
        //check that name is available or not if yes then->
        if (it.exists()) {
            val h = Handler()
            h.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
                private var time: Long = 0
                override fun run() {
                    val latitude: Double = it.child("latitude").value.toString().toDouble()
                    //get the long latitude entity value form reference
                    val longitude: Double = it.child("longitude").value.toString().toDouble()
                    //assigning the positions of lat and long
                    position = LatLng(latitude, longitude)
                    mMap.clear()
                    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(position).title("$getName"))
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position))

                    time += 1000
                    h.postDelayed(this, 1000)
                }
            }, 1000) // 1 second delay (takes millis)
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15f))
        } else Toast.makeText(this, "Location doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location didn't reach the database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

The realtime database from the firebase was as given below
[image]